# Crystal report not showing any record not even loading the report header

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

my code is:

```
string rptPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "EMSDasbaordReport\\DeductionReports\\DetailedDeductionRpt.rpt";
                rprt.Load(rptPath);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds= new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                DataTable UPTO_Table = new DataTable();
                UPTO_Table = ds.Tables[0];
                UPTO_Table.TableName = "UPTORecordtbl";                
                DataTable Check_in_Table = new DataTable();
                Check_in_Table = ds.Tables[1];
                Check_in_Table.TableName = "CheckInRecordtbl";
                DataTable Worklog_Table = new DataTable();
                Worklog_Table = ds.Tables[2];
                Worklog_Table.TableName = "WorkLogRecordtbl";
                rprt.SetDataSource(UPTO_Table);
                rprt.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(UPTO_Table);
                rprt.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(Check_in_Table);
                rprt.Subreports[2].SetDataSource(Worklog_Table);
                Session["DetailedReport"] = rprt;
                DetailedDeductionRpt.ReportSource = rprt;
```

i am getting a blank crystal report. I have three tables in my dataset "dsdeductionReport.xsd" with the same name. And my report is getting the data from these tables of my dataset.

Comment: It seems you have 1 main report, then 3 sub-reports, And how you have designed your reports, where have you placed your subreports on main report?

Comment: Open the F12 developer tools in your browser, do you see any errors?